# Limit of composite functions condition

Tags: limits

If $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = m (exists) $ Show that $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f \circ g(x)=f\left(\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)\right)=f(m)$, only if $f$ is continuous at $g(x)=m$ . Is the  reverse also true ?

> What i did was that $f(g(x))$ continuity depends indirectly on $g(x)$ so if $g(x)$ is not a point in the domain of $f(x)$ then the continuity will not make any sense . So if we assume its a point in the domain then for that point limit value only exists if the function is continuous there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $f$ is continuous at $m$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(g(x))=\lim_{y\rightarrow m}f(y)=f(m).$
- Now if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(g(x))=f(m)$, then $f$ is not necessarily continuous at $m$. For example, take $g(x)=m+|x-a|$ and $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  1  &\text{ if }x\geq m, \\
  0  &\text{ if }x< m.
  \end{cases}$$

Comment: That only condition how we prove it Sir?

Comment: If you want to do it explicitely : let $\varepsilon>0$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $m$, there exists $\delta'>0$ such that 
$$|m-y|<\delta' \Rightarrow |f(m)-f(y)|<\varepsilon.$$
There exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$|a-x|<\delta \Rightarrow |m-g(x)|=|g(a)-g(x)|<\delta'.$$
Thus for $|a-x|<\delta$, $|f(g(a))-f(g(x))|=|f(m)-f(g(x))|<\varepsilon.$

Comment: Okay thanks : )